# Using cut to filter a fixed width file

Tags: awk, grep, cut

Let's say I have a file like so:

```
1        10        20        30        40       50
==================================================
foofoofoo1111111111bblah      moreblahblblahblah
foofoofoo2          foofoo              stuffhere
```

=================================================

I want to return all rows where positions 11-20 and 31-40 are blank.  I can identify them using cut:

```
cut -b 11-20,31-40 < source.txt
```

That returns the characters in those positions.

```
====================
111111111bmoreblahbl

====================
```

The second row (ignoring the rows of ===) is all blanks. 
I want to redirect the entire row where those characters are blank/spaces (so the second row here) to a new file.  I can't figure out how to combine cut and grep to do this. Surely this has to possible, but I can't work it out.

Comment: Where does 111111111 come from? Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus - dang it, sorry, copy/paste mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? Using awk:

```
$ awk 'substr($0,11,10) substr($0,31,10)~/^ *$/' file
foofoofoo2          foofoo              stuffhere
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
substr($0,11,10) substr($0,31,10)~/^ *$/ # positions 11-20 and 31-40 are all space
' file
```

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep "^.\{10\} \{10\}.\{10\} \{10\}" file
```

From the start (`^`) there are 10 any chars (`.\{10\}`) then 10 spaces (`\{10\}`) and repeat.

**Edit**:

Shorter version of the `grep`:

```
$ grep "^\(.\{10\} \{10\}\)\{2\}" file
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='10 10 10 10' '$2$4~/^ *$/' file
foofoofoo2          foofoo              stuffhere
```